# Create an exe or similar file

Tags: java, swing

I've written the below Java code. After referring to multiple post finally made a GUI ;-) in swing.

**GUI:**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class DummyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField srcTextField;
    private JTextField destTextField;
    private JButton btnNewButton;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DummyFrame frame = new DummyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public DummyFrame() {
        setTitle("DummyFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 635, 452);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JButton srcBtn = new JButton("Source Excel");
        srcBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
                fChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
                File f = fChoose.getSelectedFile();
                srcTextField.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });

        srcTextField = new JTextField();
        srcTextField.setColumns(10);

        destTextField = new JTextField();
        destTextField.setColumns(10);

        JButton destBtn = new JButton("Output Excel");
        destBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser();
                fChoose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fChoose.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (fChoose.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    destTextField.setText(fChoose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + "\\");
                    System.out.println(fChoose.getCurrentDirectory());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No Selection");
                }

            }
        });
        final JTextArea outputTextArea = new JTextArea();
        btnNewButton = new JButton("Convert");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CreateNxi_Main createNxi_Main = new CreateNxi_Main();
                try {
                    createNxi_Main.getInputAndOutputPaths(srcTextField.getText(), destTextField.getText() + "\\",
                            outputTextArea);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addGap(10)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(destTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 421,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(18)
                                        .addComponent(destBtn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97,
                                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addContainerGap())
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(srcTextField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 421,
                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addGap(18)
                                                .addComponent(srcBtn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 97,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGap(63))))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(261, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(241))
                .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(outputTextArea, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 599, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(gl_contentPane
                .createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING).addComponent(srcBtn).addComponent(
                        srcTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addGap(20).addComponent(destTextField,
                                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup().addGap(18).addComponent(destBtn, 0, 0,
                                Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(18).addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18).addComponent(outputTextArea, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}
```

**CreteNxi_Main**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateNxi_Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String startFormattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(startFormattedDate);
        String endFormattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(endFormattedDate);
        Date d1 = sdf.parse(startFormattedDate);
        Date d2 = sdf.parse(endFormattedDate);
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
    }

    public void getInputAndOutputPaths(String inPath, String outPath, JTextArea outputTextArea) throws Exception {
        String filePath = inPath;
        String output = outPath;

        System.out.println("Src is " + filePath.toString());
        System.out.println("Dest Path is " + outPath.toString());
        // String destDirectory = "D:\\News\\nxis\\output";
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        System.out.println(rows);
        CreateNxi createNxi = new CreateNxi();
        for (int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
            String guid = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).toString();
            String collection = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString();
            outputTextArea.append(guid + "\n");
            // System.out.println(collection + "\t" + guid);
            createNxi.createFiles(guid, collection, output);
        }
        wb.close();
    }

}
```

**CreteNxi:**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class CreateNxi {

    void createFiles(String guid, String collection, String output) throws Exception {
        String input = "D:\\News\\nxis\\Template - change GUID.nxi";
        String replaceGuid = guid;
        String replaceCollection = collection;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new File(input));
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("n-extract-guid");

        NodeList nodeList1 = document.getElementsByTagName("n-extract-request");
        for (int x = 0, size = nodeList.getLength(); x < size; x++)

        {

            Node docIDValue = (Node) nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("guid");
            String docIDval = docIDValue.getNodeValue();
            docIDValue.setNodeValue(docIDval.replaceAll(docIDval, replaceGuid));

        } // Collection
        for (int x1 = 0, size1 = nodeList1.getLength(); x1 < size1; x1++)

        {

            Node collectionIDValue = (Node) nodeList1.item(x1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("verifycollection");
            String collectionIDval = collectionIDValue.getNodeValue();
            collectionIDValue.setNodeValue(collectionIDval.replaceAll(collectionIDval, replaceCollection));

        }
        new File(output).mkdir();
        output += replaceGuid + ".nxi";
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(new File(output)));
        // System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

The working is as below, we select source(.xlsx file) and destination(Folder) and once hit on convert, the process is done. Here I have below query.

1. I don't want to install eclipse in all the systems and run it, is there a way that i can make a .exe or some format of file that i can send it to them.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask 1 question instead of 5. Also, only post the relevant code, instead of your entire project.

Comment: I thought that posting single question for 5 same topics would be easy for ones who are viewing rather posting 5 different

Comment: You are working with Java, so you would not make a .exe but you would make n executable jar. http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

But you should actually have split this up into multiple questions.

Comment: Hi @DylanMeeus, Thanks for that info. I'll split my question

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you turned this into a seperate question I will answer it here again. 
To create a jar file, take a look at this:

You are working with Java, so you would not make a .exe but you would make an executable jar. (Not bound to Windows, and runs on any machine that has the Java VM installed) http://skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Comment: Created a seperate question for the Other, Thanks